# Passing C# window handle to unmanaged code - Cross-thread exception

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, pinvoke, marshalling

I've run into an issue recently where attempting to implement a real-time video capture with a video capture library and capture card.  The unmanaged library is much faster at processing the data than I can manually, so it seems the way to go.  The unmanaged library is looking for a window handle for a control to update.

The Platform Invoke for the source works fine on a one-off update and when I thread it with my own Invoke, so I know the types are all correct and that it's marshaling properly.

The main issue is that when I attempt to thread the operation and pass the window handle directly to unmanaged code, I get the dreaded "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception.

I understand the problem, just not quite sure how to fix it.  So, how do I use a delegate and "BeginInvoke()" method on control when unmanaged code just needs the window handle?  Is it even possible to arrange this?

Here's a snippet of the unmanaged library functionality:

```
class Video
    {
        [DllImport("video.dll", EntryPoint = "imagePlot", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int imagePlot(IntPtr windowHandle, byte[] imageBuffer);

        private PictureBox _control;
        public Video(PictureBox control)
        {
            _control = control;
        }

        public void CaptureAndUpdate()
        {
            // capture video
            byte[] video = Capture();

            // plot video
            imagePlot(_control.Handle, video);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only change properties on UI elements from the main UI thread. Check this [url](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/507f5d4b-d33e-40e0-8802-05fe46519658/crossthread-operation-not-valid?forum=csharpgeneral),